# Signing Key Rollover and Naturally Expiring Access Tokens

Tags: java, jwt, azure-active-directory, encryption-asymmetric, jwk

I am developing an app that uses Azure AD as my OAuth2.0 provider. Azure has a Jwks endpoint with multiple public keys, one of which its corresponding private key was used to sign my token.  My app handles signing key resolving by inspecting the keyid out of the authorization header and determining which key the token was signed with by looking it up in a cache.

My application fetches the keys from the endpoint every 5 minutes and stores them in a cache until the next fetch occurs.  Let's say a user gets issued a token signed with Key#1. If Key#1 gets swapped out with a key#2 on the Jwks endpoint, and my app fetches Key#2 - caches it, and then attempts to verify the signature of the token signed with Key#1, then the token validation will obviously fail.

How can I allow tokens signed with keys no longer at the Jwks endpoint to still be used to validate the token until the token's natural expire time is reached?

Comment: Did you get an answer on this?

Comment: Yes. If the key provider no longer has the key at its /certs endpoint, then failing is the best thing to do.  If you really want to support this, you could cache several keys and use the date and time a token was issued in order to determine which cached key to try. bottom line is the provider is the authority, so you should respect what its key set currently is.  there's not too much need to build in this functionality, just have your user re-authenticate.